# Change git url to short url

Tags: git

How can I change my git repo url?

Example:

```
git@server:/var/git/project.git
```

to

```
git@server:project.git
```

Comment: If you're using ssh transport, path would be relative to user's home directory. For rsync, use `/etc/rsyncd.conf`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are connecting by SSH you will need to update the git users home directory to /var/git

Alternately you can symlink the folders to the home directory. If you plan on being able to easily add new projects in the future I would change the home dir. If not I would add the symlink